# What is x_train.reshape() and What it Does?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, mnist

Using MNIST Dataset

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

# MNIST dataset parameters
num_classes = 10 # total classes (0-9 digits)
num_features = 784 # data features (img shape: 28*28)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Convert to float32
x_train, x_test = np.array(x_train, np.float32), np.array(x_test, np.float32)

# Flatten images to 1-D vector of 784 features (28*28)
x_train, x_test = x_train.reshape([-1, num_features]), x_test.reshape([-1, num_features])

# Normalize images value from [0, 255] to [0, 1]
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255., x_test / 255.
```

At the **15th Line** of these Code which is,

`x_train, x_test = x_train.reshape([-1, num_features]), x_test.reshape([-1, num_features])`. I can't Understand what these reshaping really does in our Dataset..?? Please Explain me.

Comment: Did you print `x_train` and `x_test` before and after the reshaping?

Comment: The comment just on top of the line explains it: `# Flatten images to 1-D vector of 784 features (28*28)`

Answer (score 0):

As commented in 14th line it Flattens images to 1-D vector of 784 features (28*28) i.e., it coverts the 2-D NumPy array of dimension 28*28 to a 1-D array of length 784

Answer (score 0):

`reshape()` function is generally used to change the shape of an array without changing the data.
`x_train.reshape([-1,num_features])` in this command `x_train` will be converted into 2D array. 
. **Here,** `-1` is used when you aren't sure about the dimension you let NumPy to calculate for you. 
**For example:** The shape of `x_train` is `(144,)`, which is 1D array you want to convert this into 2D format. Imagine, `num_fetures = 3`. When you run `x_train.reshape([-1,num_features])`, the shape of `x_train` will changed into: **144/3 = 48** for the `-1`. So, final output is `(48,3).`

**Note:** The previous shape of `x_train` must be divisible by `num_features` to obtain the dimension for `-1`.

Comment: [**W3SCHOOL**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_reshape.asp) .